# Manejo de archivos en c

Tags: c

tengo el siguiente código para leer un archivo. Lo que quiero es leer hasta que se lea un espacio, o un paréntesis, ya sea de apertura o de cierre. Tengo el siguiente código, pero al ejecutarlo no se me imprime nada. Alguna idea de qué hacer para comparar el carácter con alguno de esos delimitadores?

```
int dbus_input_data(const char *path, input_data_t *datos){
    FILE *fp;
    char caracter;
    char delimitador = ' ';
    fp = fopen(path, "r");
    int pos = 0;
    if (fp == NULL){
        return 1;
    }
    printf("\nEl contenido del archivo de prueba es \n\n");
    do{
        caracter = fgetc(fp);
        //strcpy(caracter, buffer[pos]);
        printf("%c", caracter);
        pos ++;
    }while ((caracter != delimitador)); 
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

El archivo que recibo por parámetro contiene la siguiente línea:

taller.hellodbus /taller/greeter taller.Dbus.Greeter printHello(Hola!)

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Has comprobado si la función te devuelve `1` o si el archivo, por algún casual, tiene un espacio antes de tiempo?

Comment: Depurando descubrirías el problema en menos tiempo que te ha llevado publicar la pregunta. Verías qué caracteres lee y por qué se sale del bucle.

Answer (score 0):

```
int dbus_input_data(const char *path)
{
   FILE *fp;
   char caracter;
   char c;
   char delimitador = ' ';
   fp = fopen(path, "r");
   if (fp == NULL)
   {
      perror("Error in opening file");
      return (-1);
   }
   do
   {
      c = fgetc(fp);
      if (feof(fp) || c == delimitador)
         break;
      printf("%c", c);
   } while (1);
   fclose(fp);
   return (0);
}


int main(void)
{
   dbus_input_data("file_to_read");
}
```

La salida es la que esperábamos:

`taller.hellodbus`

Si sigues teniendo problemas seguramente sea problema de permisos de archivo, puedes comprobar los permisos en las propiedades del archivo:

[Explicación de cómo cambiarlo en windows](https://es.wikihow.com/cambiar-los-permisos-de-archivo-en-Windows-7)

[Cómo hacerlo con Chmod en linux y mac](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/tutorial-comando-chmod.html)

Answer (score 0):

La función fscanf lee el archivo hasta que encuentra un espacio. La sintaxis es:
fscanf(Nombre del puntero sin el operador *, cadena, formato).
Ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char Dato[30];
    char Texto[30] = "numero = 5\nprint(numero)"; // Texto que se guardará en el archivo

    FILE *Archivo = fopen(Prueba.txt, "w+"); // Apertura de un archivo

    fprintf(Archivo, "%s\n", Texto); // Escritura de un archivo

    rewind(Archivo); // Mover el cursor hasta el inicio del archivo
    fscanf(Archivo, "%s", &Dato);

    printf("%s", Dato);

    fclose(Archivo); // Cierre de un archivo

    return 0;
}
```